# How can I split a dataframe into multiple dataframes based on timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

Let's say I have a dataframe which contains content and different timestamps for each entry; how can I split the dataframe into two (or more) dataframes based on the difference in timestamps? For example, if an entry starts 6 hours after the one preceeding it, then I'd like all the rows coming after it (which are within 6 hour time interval) to be grouped together. You may assume that the timestamps come in ascending order in the dataframe.

Here's an example df:

```
         content                  timestamp
0    Content_100 2023-06-28 21:15:29.605277
1     Content_91 2023-07-10 21:15:29.605277
2     Content_49 2023-07-11 21:15:29.605277
3     Content_76 2023-06-22 21:15:29.605277
4     Content_42 2023-07-04 21:15:29.605277
5     Content_39 2023-07-04 21:15:29.605277
6     Content_76 2023-06-29 21:15:29.605277
7     Content_85 2023-06-27 21:15:29.605277
```

Comment: Should the values be sorted? In your example almost all values are >6h of each other, did you mean 6 days?

Comment: Can you also provide the expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not fully clear, but to set up a group you could use:

```
df['group'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).sort_values()
                 .diff().gt('6h').cumsum()
               )
```

Output:

```
       content                  timestamp  group
0  Content_100 2023-06-28 21:15:29.605277      2
1   Content_91 2023-07-10 21:15:29.605277      5
2   Content_49 2023-07-11 21:15:29.605277      6
3   Content_76 2023-06-22 21:15:29.605277      0
4   Content_42 2023-07-04 21:15:29.605277      4
5   Content_39 2023-07-04 21:15:29.605277      4
6   Content_76 2023-06-29 21:15:29.605277      3
7   Content_85 2023-06-27 21:15:29.605277      1
```

Intermediate with sorted timestamps and difference in hours to the previous time:

```
       content                  timestamp  group   diff
3   Content_76 2023-06-22 21:15:29.605277      0    NaN
7   Content_85 2023-06-27 21:15:29.605277      1  120.0
0  Content_100 2023-06-28 21:15:29.605277      2   24.0
6   Content_76 2023-06-29 21:15:29.605277      3   24.0
4   Content_42 2023-07-04 21:15:29.605277      4  120.0 # grouped
5   Content_39 2023-07-04 21:15:29.605277      4    0.0 #
1   Content_91 2023-07-10 21:15:29.605277      5  144.0
2   Content_49 2023-07-11 21:15:29.605277      6   24.0
```

To split the DataFrame in sub DataFrames you can then use:

```
out = [g for _, g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).sort_values()
                                  .diff().gt('6h').cumsum())]
```

Output:

```
[      content                  timestamp
 3  Content_76 2023-06-22 21:15:29.605277,
       content                  timestamp
 7  Content_85 2023-06-27 21:15:29.605277,
        content                  timestamp
 0  Content_100 2023-06-28 21:15:29.605277,
       content                  timestamp
 6  Content_76 2023-06-29 21:15:29.605277,
       content                  timestamp
 4  Content_42 2023-07-04 21:15:29.605277
 5  Content_39 2023-07-04 21:15:29.605277,
       content                  timestamp
 1  Content_91 2023-07-10 21:15:29.605277,
       content                  timestamp
 2  Content_49 2023-07-11 21:15:29.605277]
```